# Item disposed after a sort update with DynamicData

Tags: c#, dynamic-data

I am using DynamicData (6.9.1.2588) to transform items then sort them.

```
ObservableCollectionEx.ToObservableChangeSet<ReactiveList<DataItem>, DataItem>(model.Children)
                .Filter((d) => d.ViewClass == NormalizedType.TableRow)
                .Transform(d => new TableRow(d, this))
                .AutoRefresh(a => a.Index)
                .Sort(SortExpressionComparer<TableRow>.Ascending(a => a.Index))
                .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                .Bind(Rows)
             .DisposeMany()
             .Subscribe()
```

But when the property used for sorting is changed, dynamicdata call the Dispose of the transformed items (TableRow).
It does this even if I remove the DisposeMany.

I don't pass in TableRow constructor so the items are disposed but are kept in the list.

Is it a bug of dynamicdata or did I made a mistake in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.
This is done by design in DynamicData and the workaround is explained here.
https://github.com/RolandPheasant/DynamicData/issues/19

after the initial ToObservableChangeSet we must add

```
.AddKey(d => d.GetLocalId())
```

and just after the transform, we must add

```
.AsObservableCache()
.DisposeMany()
.Connect()
```

So dispose will only happen if item is removed from earlier in the chain. not when they are removed/added by the sort later in the chain.

The final code look like this

```
ObservableCollectionEx.ToObservableChangeSet<ReactiveList<DataItem>, DataItem>(model.Children)
                .AddKey(d => d.GetLocalId())
                .Filter((d) => d.ViewClass == NormalizedType.TableRow)
                .Transform(d => new TableRow(d, this))
                .DisposeMany()
                .AsObservableCache()
                .Connect()
                .AutoRefresh(a => a.Index)
                .Sort(SortExpressionComparer<TableRow>.Ascending(a => a.Index))
                .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                .Bind(Rows)
             .Subscribe()
```